# keep only files with the same basename

Tags: command-line, files, delete

How can I only keep the `.txt` files in both `imgur/images/vase` as well as `imgur/comments/vase` that pertain to the `.jpeg` files in image folder of vase?

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/imgur/images$ ls vase/
09PcZOp.jpeg  aAk8xnc.jpeg  BmlEmqV.jpeg  fYJdYsw.jpeg  JLlgK86.jpeg  P0EqiL6.jpeg  r5cwq2Z.jpeg  uYQdAkX.jpeg  wZvDVUV.jpeg  YOjY83l.jpeg
5bSmL.jpeg    aepd0Fv.gif   CXENf98.jpeg  GWZNImv.jpeg  NDKCSnv.jpeg  P6UcA4a.jpeg  t1Pvv.jpeg    VEgOghz.jpeg  xaGoY.jpeg    ZDVSteW.png
7IIMF9n.jpeg  B6L0ZWn.gif   ee8uEPA.png   HUZLjjR.jpeg  oUwwY47.jpeg  Qcr4c2x.jpeg  TurgWyF.jpeg  VpcMGTP.gif   YIbyIp7.jpeg  zeTwDul.png
7Mk599E.jpeg  bL9B5Ej.jpeg  eGFLBGj.jpeg  IYepKMc.jpeg  oUXgilJ.png   R4EdALX.png   UmzKe2R.gif   wK7EjUG.gif   YImIVh4.jpeg
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/imgur/images$ ls ../comments/vase/
09PcZOp.txt  7Mk599E.txt  B6L0ZWn.txt  CXENf98.txt  fYJdYsw.txt  IYepKMc.txt  oUwwY47.txt  P6UcA4a.txt  r5cwq2Z.txt  UmzKe2R.txt  VpcMGTP.txt  xaGoY.txt    YOjY83l.txt
5bSmL.txt    aAk8xnc.txt  bL9B5Ej.txt  ee8uEPA.txt  GWZNImv.txt  JLlgK86.txt  oUXgilJ.txt  Qcr4c2x.txt  t1Pvv.txt    uYQdAkX.txt  wK7EjUG.txt  YIbyIp7.txt  ZDVSteW.txt
7IIMF9n.txt  aepd0Fv.txt  BmlEmqV.txt  eGFLBGj.txt  HUZLjjR.txt  NDKCSnv.txt  P0EqiL6.txt  R4EdALX.txt  TurgWyF.txt  VEgOghz.txt  wZvDVUV.txt  YImIVh4.txt  zeTwDul.txt

mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/imgur/images/vase$ ls *jpeg
09PcZOp.jpeg  7Mk599E.jpeg  BmlEmqV.jpeg  fYJdYsw.jpeg  IYepKMc.jpeg  oUwwY47.jpeg  Qcr4c2x.jpeg  TurgWyF.jpeg  wZvDVUV.jpeg  YImIVh4.jpeg
5bSmL.jpeg    aAk8xnc.jpeg  CXENf98.jpeg  GWZNImv.jpeg  JLlgK86.jpeg  P0EqiL6.jpeg  r5cwq2Z.jpeg  uYQdAkX.jpeg  xaGoY.jpeg    YOjY83l.jpeg
7IIMF9n.jpeg  bL9B5Ej.jpeg  eGFLBGj.jpeg  HUZLjjR.jpeg  NDKCSnv.jpeg  P6UcA4a.jpeg  t1Pvv.jpeg    VEgOghz.jpeg  YIbyIp7.jpeg
```

For example eventually I want to have:

```
09PcZOp.txt  7Mk599E.txt  BmlEmqV.txt  fYJdYsw.txt  IYepKMc.txt  oUwwY47.txt  Qcr4c2x.txt  TurgWyF.txt  wZvDVUV.txt  YImIVh4.txt
5bSmL.txt    aAk8xnc.txt  CXENf98.txt  GWZNImv.txt  JLlgK86.txt  P0EqiL6.txt  r5cwq2Z.txt  uYQdAkX.txt  xaGoY.txt    YOjY83l.txt
7IIMF9n.txt  bL9B5Ej.txt  eGFLBGj.txt  HUZLjjR.txt  NDKCSnv.txt  P6UcA4a.txt  t1Pvv.txt    VEgOghz.txt  YIbyIp7.txt
```

Left in the imgur/comments folder.

Additionally I have all these folders:

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/imgur/images$ ls
aeroplane     baseball glove  broccoli  cell phone  dining table  frisbee   keyboards   motorcycles    plants        skateboard   teddy bear     trains
airplane      bear            bus       chair       dog           giraffe   kite        mouse          refrigerator  ski          tennis racket  truck
airplanes     bears           cake      chairs      dogs          giraffes  knife       orange         remote        skis         tie            trucks
apple         bench           cakes     clock       donut         handbag   laptop      oranges        sandwich      snowboard    toaster        tv
apples        bird            car       clocks      doughnut      horse     laptops     oven           sandwiches    spoon        toilet         umbrella
backpack      birds           carrot    couch       elephant      horses    microwave   parking meter  scissors      sports ball  toilets        vase
banana        book            cars      cow         elephants     hotdog    motorbike   person         sheep         stop sign    toothbrush     wine glass
bananas       books           cat       cows        fire hydrant  hotdogs   motorbikes  pizza          sink          suitcase     traffic light  zebra
baseball bat  bowl            cats      cup         fork          keyboard  motorcycle  plant          sinks         surfboard    train          zebras
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears that the image files and the text files have a basename in common (as in basename.pic and basename.txt)

Comment: yes, and that name is unique (it's an imgur ID) @ElderGeek

Comment: So you wish to remove the comment files in  `imgur/comments/vase` that don't have a matching image in `imgur/images/vase` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Python script did the job:

```py
import os.path as osp
import os
import re


for directory in os.listdir('images'):
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('images/'+directory+'/') if not re.match(r'([a-za-z]|[0-9])+.*\.jpeg', f)]

    for f in files:
        complete_file_path = 'comments/'+ directory+'/'+f[:-4]+'.txt'
        if osp.exists(complete_file_path):
            os.remove(complete_file_path)
```